# how to change variable value on parent form using child form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

on my parent form I have

```
int count;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter.Text = "TOTAL: "+Convert.ToString(count);
        time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
    }
```

on my child form, I have

```
int counter;
public void view()
    {
          //codes//codes//codes//
       counter = pview.Rows.Count;
    }
```

I want to set the count = counter..
I tried

```
count = childform.counter;
```

but it didn't work..

Help me. Help you.
-Lina Inverse

Comment: I figured it out! Finally!
I just change the

    int count;

into

    public static int count;
and on my child form

    parent.count = counter;

Answer (score 0):

If you want parent form to access some variable of child form you have to store a reference to child form in the parent form. Also your child form should provide public variable or a method to allow access it from outside.

Let's assume you're running `MainForm` which will show `ChildForm`:

```
public partial class MainForm
{

    private ChildForm _childForm;

    public void ShowChildForm()
    {
        _childForm = new ChildForm();
        _childForm.Show();
    }

    public void ReadRowCount()
    {
        if (_childForm != null)
        {
            // Reading variable from child form
            int rowCount = _childForm.RowCount;
        }
    }
}

public partial class ChildForm
{
    public int RowCount { get; private set; }
}
```